# construction problem with compass

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

There is given a line (AB) , a point C in the line $ C \in (AB) $ and a circle $ \Omega $
Construct the circle $ \omega $ tangent with $ \Omega$ and also tangent in C with (AB) .It should be done with ruler and compass.
I can draw (OC) that intercepts $ \Omega $ in E. Than I draw a perpendicular line with (OC) in E. I don't know what else to do.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do here.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I think it is impossible with a line and a circle put in that positions..

Comment: I am trying to draw a circle $\omega$  tanget with the line (AB) in point C and also tangent with the circle $\Omega$ . Point C, line (AB) and $\Omega$ are alredy given

Comment: You want to do that by just "compass and ruler" or by analytic geometry?

Comment: It's possible to construct with ruler and compass if you're given a unit length. This construction only involves square-roots, addition, and division, all of which can be done via ruler and compass.

Comment: yes, it should be done with ruler and compass

Comment: Ok, so next time please indicate such a "detail" in your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagining the circle we want expanding by the radius of $\Omega$, we see that a circle with the same center goes through the center of $\Omega$ and a $C$ shifted perpendicular to $AB$ by the radius of $\Omega$.

Draw line $CD$ perpendicular to $AB$ through $C$ and then draw the perpendicular bisector of the center of $\Omega$ and the shifted $C$. The circle we want is centered at the intersection of the two lines.

[image]

Comment: how can I prove this, please?

Comment: sorry, I didn't see you had provided the same answer ..